# jquery remove not removing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

so I've got this form:

```
<form id="imageinputpopup" class=suggestionsubmit style="display: none">
    <span>Add a thing!</span><br/>
    <label>url: </label><input name="imageurl" type="url"><br/>
    <label>file: </label><input name="imagefile" type="file"><br/>
    <input type='hidden' name='schoolid' class="schoolid">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and this click handler:

```
$(".allow-submission").live('click', function(){
    if($(this).attr('inputtype')=="colorpicker"){
        ....
    } else if($(this).attr('inputtype')=="image"){
        remove_hidden("#imageinputpopup");
        add_fieldname($(this), $("#imageinputpopup"));
        $("#imageinputpopup").dialog();
    } ....
});
```

remove_hidden looks like:

```
function remove_hidden(element){
    alert($(element).children('.fieldname').length);
    $(element+'.fieldname').remove();
    alert($(element).children('.fieldname').length);
}
```

and add_fieldname looks like:

```
function add_fieldname(element, addto){
    var elementname = document.createElement('input');
    elementname.type = 'hidden';
    elementname.name = 'fieldname';
    elementname.value = element.attr('fieldname').replace(' ', '_');
    $(elementname).addClass('fieldname');
    addto.append(elementname);
}
```

as I expect, with each click, a tag like this is added:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldname" value="mascot_image" class="fieldname">
```

but remove_hidden isn't removing!
I know the selector is right because the alert is exactly the number of these input tags, but they're just not getting removed. Why? I also tried `$(element+).remove('.fieldname');` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you put up a demo?  http://sscce.org

Comment: is `$(element+'.fieldname')` selecting something? try to `console.log($(element+'.fieldname'))` it. also as already mentioned you can put demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `element.attr('fieldname')`... AFAIK, there's no attribute called `fieldname`.

Comment: Yes, as I said, " I know the selector is right because the alert is exactly the number of these input tags, but they're just not getting removed". I'll try to put up a fiddle.

Comment: Using `fieldname` as both a `class` and a name of an input field is almost certainly going to lead to confusion.

Comment: `$(element).children('.fieldname')` and `$(element+'.fieldname')` are different things, as already mentioned in two answers - try to add space before dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line of `remove_hidden`

```
//Select the element with the id of element AND has the class of fieldname
$(element+'.fieldname').remove();
```

Try putting a space before the `.` like so:

```
//Select the children of element which have a class of fieldname
$(element+' .fieldname').remove();
```

EDIT: Added comments above to clear things up a bit

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why $(element).remove('.fieldname') didn't work?

Comment: That would be because your original selector is choosing something that has a class of `fieldname`, but you really wanted to remove the children of `element` with the class of `fieldname`

Comment: Hmmm, i misread your comment. I am not sure why `$(element).remove('.fieldname')` didn't work.

Comment: It's because the selector in remove "filters the set of matched elements" to decide what to remove. https://api.jquery.com/remove/
Their documentation threw me off at first.
What you are trying to remove already needs to be in the collection (no selector in the remove method would remove the entire collection).

Answer (score 1):

try replacing

```
$(element+'.fieldname').remove();
```

with

```
$(element+' .fieldname').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get this source right, on one hand you don't have an ID on the input you get when you add a fieldname with the add_fieldname function. You might want to set that for ease of use.
On the other hand, in the remove_hidden function you alert out the `element .fieldname`, but trying to remove the `element.fieldname` (notice the missing space in front of the class name), so I presume you need this in the remove_hidden function:

```
$(element+' .fieldname').remove();
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's because .remove([selector]) ["filters the set of matched elements"](http://api.jquery.com/remove) to decide what to remove.

Their documentation threw me off at first. What you are trying to remove already needs to be in the collection (no selector in the remove method would remove the entire collection).

**Ex: Remove input.fieldname:**

```
$(element).find('.fieldname').remove('.fieldname');
```

or (for  the larger case collection case):

```
$(element).find('input').remove('.fieldname');
```

**Ex: Do NOT remove input.fieldname:**

```
$(element).find('input').remove('.notfieldname');
```